# Remove/Replace wrong character from SF fields

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I wolud like to find and remove some imported special characters. For example I get some leads via api which have a German Umlaut like ö but in SF it looks like Ã¼. This wrong characters can be found in first and last name and also in the company field.

My first try was a flow wit a decision for all possible wrong formats (ä,ö,ü,ß and Ä,Ö,Ü,ß) and replace them. But if I replace them the whole field would be then only the one correct character. Right?

So is there another solution for that?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: If SFDC is seeing value as 2+ chars, then the incoming data is not in UTF-8

Comment: #cropredy Ok. But the question still remains the same: How can I replace these characters with the correct ones?

Answer (score 0):

Got my solution. I use SUBSTITUTE within a formula field as a variable, assign the new variable as the new field value and update later on the field itself.
Worked as expected even with multi substitute.

[image]